# How to detect if a number is greater than Long.MAX value

Tags: java, numbers

My application will get number as string from end user. If the number is not numeric, i have to throw error message by saying that to provide number. This i can fix by using   NumberFormatException. Another scenario is, user entered greater than Long.MAX value. How i can check this case and give error message to the user to enter smaller number than Long.MAX value? I should not use any third party or open source lib to fix this issue. Even if they are providing solution, How they are resolving it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `BigInteger` to parse user input and compare the result with Long.MAX_VALUE

```
String userInput = ...;
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(userInput);
if(bigInt.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE)) > 0) {
    throw new Exception(userInput + ": value is too large");
}
```

Comment: Yes. This solution is working fine. Is this indicates that instead of Integer / Long / Double, We can use only BigInteger?  Or When we can use BigInteger?

Comment: `Long` object can't hold values larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE` so you have to use `BigInteger` to parse the input and detect if the input satisfy your restrictions. After that you can call `bigInt.longValue()` to get `long` value and process it further

Comment: No one should ever write `throw new Exception(…)` in code.  Always throw a subclass of Exception (like IllegalArgumentException) instead.  Throwing Exception forces other code to catch Exception, which prevents programmer errors such as NullPointerExceptions from being seen and fixed.

Comment: @VGR how it is related to the original question?

Comment: Readers will often copy code verbatim, especially from accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the entered number is greater than `Long.MAX` value, then what will you do next. It will cause an error as you don't know where to store it.

Better way is to check at the time of user input is in range or not. If it is greater than `Long.MAX`,  store it in `BigInteger`

Comment: How to check whether entered value is in range or not?

Comment: I think @Yaroslav Rudykh answer did it the same way.

Comment: Yes. Tried it. Working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and the [`longValueExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValueExact--) method, and catch exceptions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("123");
    test("9223372036854775807");  // Long.MAX_VALUE
    test("-9223372036854775808"); // Long.MIN_VALUE
    test("9223372036854775808");  // Long.MAX_VALUE + 1
    test("-9223372036854775809"); // Long.MIN_VALUE - 1
    test("abc");
}
private static void test(String input) {
    long longVal;
    try {
        longVal = new BigInteger(input).longValueExact();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Value is not a valid integer number: " + input);
        return;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("Value exceeds range of long: " + input);
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Got valid long value: " + longVal);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Got valid long value: 123
Got valid long value: 9223372036854775807
Got valid long value: -9223372036854775808
Value exceeds range of long: 9223372036854775808
Value exceeds range of long: -9223372036854775809
Value is not a valid integer number: abc
```

Comment: This solution also works as expected. Great. But which one is better by performance / memory? 1. compareTo method with Long.MAX arg or 2. longValueExact method

Answer (score 0):

You can access the max value using Long.MAX_VALUE and check the user entered value in if condition.

Comment: How to check in if condition whether entered input is in range or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without using an extra class other than `Java` core

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE("9223372036854775807"));      // false
    System.out.println(isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE("9223372036854775806"));      // false
    System.out.println(isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE("9223372036854775808"));      // true
    System.out.println(isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE("645459223372036854775807")); // true
    System.out.println(isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE("922"));                      // false
}

public static boolean isLargerThanLONGMAXVALUE (String number) {
    String longMax = String.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    if (number.length() > longMax.length()) return true;
    if (number.length() < longMax.length()) return false;
    long a, b = 0;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < number.length() ; i++){
        a = Long.parseLong(number.substring(0, i));
        b = Long.parseLong(longMax.substring(0, i));
        if (a > b) return true;
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(number.substring(number.length()-1, number.length())) > 
        Integer.parseInt(longMax.substring(number.length()-1, number.length())))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Treating the string as a `BigInteger` and doing the comparison is the best way.  But here's another just to show that there's usually more than one way to accomplish something:

```
public boolean isInRange(String number) {
    String maxValue = Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    number = number.replaceFirst("^0+", "");  // remove leading zeroes
    return number.length() < maxValue.length() ||
           (number.length() == maxValue.length() &&
            number.compareTo(maxValue) <= 0);
}
```

This assumes that `number` is composed entirely of digits (no negative sign).

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  val n = input.toLong()
}catch(e: Exception){
  // invalid Long
}
```